# FFMPEG-API Add Subtitle to an MPEG-TS Stream

Tags: ffmpeg

We have a Video file we want to stream it over UDP in mpegts.
This is working perfectly with ffmpeg API.

Now we want to add subtitle's to this stream.

i'll try to load subtitle file and add stream to our output context not working
i'll try to dynamicaly add subtitle not working too

If Anyone has an idea.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

MPEG-TS format only supports DVBSUB or DVBTELETEXT formats and both are bitmap-based.

Comment: Yes, i'll try to set Bitmap in AVSubtitleRect as i can see on stackoverflow but not working. All my subtitles are in bitmap format (DVBSUB)